# pass parameters to docker entrypoint

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile

```
FROM    java:8
ADD     my_app.jar /srv/app/my_app.jar
WORKDIR /srv/app
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my_app.jar", "--spring.config.location=classpath:/srv/app/configs/application.properties"]
```

How I can do dynamic paramethers for java without `./run.sh` in entrypoint? ( as `-Dversion=$version` or others )

I want pass this parameters when start container.

`--entrypoint something` doesn't work on Docker 1.11 ;(

Comment: Did you try just putting that at the end of your run (or similar) statement as a CMD (command)? It should append it to the ENTRYPOINT. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/cmd-default-command-or-options -- or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 12):

You can append your dynamic parameters at the end of the `docker run ...`. You haven't specified any `CMD` instruction, so it'll work.

What is actually run without specifying any command at the end, when running the `docker run ...`, is this:

`ENTRYPOINT CMD` (it's concatenated and there is a space in between)

So you can also use something like

```
...
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "my_app.jar"]
CMD ["--spring.config.location=classpath:/srv/app/configs/application.properties"]
```

which means, when using

`docker run mycontainer` the

`java -jar my_app.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/srv/app/configs/application.properties`

will be invoked (the default case), but when running

`docker run mycontainer --spring.config.location=classpath:/srv/app/configs/some_other_application.properties -Dversion=$version`

it'll be run w/ different property file and with the system property called `version` (overriding the default case)

Comment: Doing the same thing doesn't work for me.I get `docker: Error response from daemon: invalid header field value "oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"-Dversion=1243\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n".` The only difference I can see is the other parameters I use on the command line, and maybe putting them before the docker image name.

Comment: java is not in your $PATH.. so either add it or use the full path to the java binary